# parse.com getting pointer data from currentUser

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

i have a pointer key in PFUser and I'm trying to retrieve the object it's pointing to. I've seen many examples about querying for it but there shouldn't be any need for that, since parse has the fetch method and it's a pointer of PFUser class, so I'm using this:

```
PFObject *menu = [[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"menuID"] fetchIfNeeded];
```

I know my current user has an object being pointed to in that key but i get a null menu object all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wain was correct in saying that you need to fetch the currentUser. However, you have to keep in mind that we're working with multiple threads if you want to use fetchInBackground. To keep in on a single thread, simply use [[PFUser currentUser] fetch], but keep in mind that this can cause hanging or blocking for your user when internet connection is bad. Below is a sample of how to use this more effectively. (Same issue with the fetch vs. fetchInBackground for the menu) We have to fetch the menu as well, since it is a pointer and so the currentUser will only fetch the pointer and not the whole object.

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        PFObject *menu = object[@"menuID"];
        [menu fetch];
        // Execute any code that needs the menu here, or store it in your viewController (or other class variable) if you need to save it for later  

        // Alternately, you could use this:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [menu fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *fetchedMenu, NSError *menuError) {
                if(!menuError){
                    // Execute any code that needs the menu here, or store it
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@", menuError);
                }
            }];
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: thank you so much to the both of you, very helpful explanation and example

Answer (score 0):

By default `currentUser` doesn't have any custom added columns of data populated. You need to fetch the user to download that data and then you can use it locally.

Alternatively your oils us cloud code and save a network request.

Comment: do I just do [[pfuser currentuser] fetch] ?

Comment: so now i did PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackGround];
and then to test it I check:

  if ([user objectForKey:@"menuID"] != NULL) {
        //
    }

but I'm getting this error -[BFTask objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Are you running these two in sequence? fetchInBackground runs on a separate thread, so you can't actually use the currentUser object until after that fetch completes. Try using a callback and setting your menu item in the callback.